# Letsencrypt certs generated but getting TLS error with docker traefik using dns acme challenge

Tags: docker, cloudflare, traefik, lets-encrypt, certbot

i am following this doc https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-dns/ to setup docker traefik using the dns acme challenge for letsencrypt

i am able to have the certs generated by each service that request it dynamically and in the logs it shows

```
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate(s) to validate [\"redis.example.com\"]..." providerName=myresolver.acme rule="Host(`redis.example.com`)" routerName=redis@docker
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="Domains [\"redis.example.com\"] need ACME certificates generation for domains \"redis.example.com\"." rule="Host(`redis.example.com`)" routerName=redis@docker providerName=myresolver.acme
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="Loading ACME certificates [redis.example.com]..." providerName=myresolver.acme rule="Host(`redis.example.com`)" routerName=redis@docker
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] AuthURL: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/233260818"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: Could not find solver for: tls-alpn-01"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: Could not find solver for: http-01"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: use dns-01 solver"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: Preparing to solve DNS-01"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] cloudflare: new record for redis.example.com, ID 8da8eadd16f8e99c8b7ce8412f124ad7"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: Trying to solve DNS-01"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:27Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: Checking DNS record propagation using [127.0.0.11:53]"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:29Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] Wait for propagation [timeout: 2m0s, interval: 2s]"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:30Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
time="2021-08-09T21:21:36Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] The server validated our request"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:36Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: Cleaning DNS-01 challenge"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:36Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] acme: Validations succeeded; requesting certificates"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:42Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [redis.example.com] Server responded with a certificate."
time="2021-08-09T21:21:42Z" level=debug msg="Certificates obtained for domains [redis.example.com]" providerName=myresolver.acme rule="Host(`redis.example.com`)" routerName=redis@docker
time="2021-08-09T21:21:42Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider myresolver.acme: {\"http\":{},\"tls\":{}}" providerName=myresolver.acme
time="2021-08-09T21:21:42Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) adminer.example.com"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:42Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) redis.example.com"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:42Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
```

but am still getting TLS error when i visit the services endpoints `redis.example.com` and `adminer.example.com`

```
time="2021-08-09T21:21:44Z" level=debug msg="Adding route for adminer.example.com with TLS options default" entryPointName=web
time="2021-08-09T21:21:44Z" level=debug msg="Adding route for redis.example.com with TLS options default" entryPointName=web
time="2021-08-09T21:21:44Z" level=debug msg="Adding route for redis.example.com with TLS options default" entryPointName=websecure
time="2021-08-09T21:21:44Z" level=debug msg="Try to challenge certificate for domain [adminer.example.com] found in HostSNI rule" providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=adminer@docker rule="Host(`adminer.example.com`)"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:44Z" level=debug msg="Try to challenge certificate for domain [redis.example.com] found in HostSNI rule" routerName=redis@docker rule="Host(`redis.example.com`)" providerName=myresolver.acme
time="2021-08-09T21:21:44Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate(s) to validate [\"redis.example.com\"]..." providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=redis@docker rule="Host(`redis.example.com`)"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:44Z" level=debug msg="No ACME certificate generation required for domains [\"redis.example.com\"]." providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=redis@docker rule="Host(`redis.example.com`)"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:44Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate(s) to validate [\"adminer.example.com\"]..." providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=adminer@docker rule="Host(`adminer.example.com`)"
time="2021-08-09T21:21:44Z" level=debug msg="No ACME certificate generation required for domains [\"adminer.example.com\"]." providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=adminer@docker rule="Host(`adminer.example.com`)"
time="2021-08-09T21:25:46Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.0.17:57716: remote error: tls: unknown certificate"
time="2021-08-09T21:25:46Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.0.17:57718: remote error: tls: unknown certificate"
```

here is content of `./letsencrypt/acme.json`

```
{
    "myresolver": {
      "Account": {
        "Email": "user@email.com",
        "Registration": {
          "body": {
            "status": "valid",
            "contact": [
              "mailto:user@email.com"
            ]
          },
          "uri": "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/123"
        },
        "PrivateKey": "MIIJEjdXXXXX==",
        "KeyType": "4096"
      },
      "Certificates": [
        {
          "domain": {
            "main": "adminer.example.com"
          },
          "certificate": "LS0tXXXXX==",
          "key": "LS0tLXXXXX==",
          "Store": "default"
        },
        {
          "domain": {
            "main": "redis.example.com"
          },
          "certificate": "LS0tLXXXX",
          "key": "LS0tLXXXX",
          "Store": "default"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

so what am i missing or need to fix?

here is `traefik_docker_compose.yaml` file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=user@email.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.traefik
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - traefik_network

networks:
  traefik_network:
     name: traefik_network
```

and `adminer_docker_compose.yaml` file for example

```
version: '3.9'

services:
   adminer:
     image: adminer:latest
     restart: always
     container_name: adminer
     networks:
       - adminer_network
       - traefik_network
     labels:
       - "traefik.enable=true"
       - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_network"
       - "traefik.http.services.adminer.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
       - "traefik.http.routers.adminer.entrypoints=web"
       - "traefik.http.routers.adminer.rule=Host(`adminer.example.com`)"
       - "traefik.http.routers.adminer.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
   
networks:
    adminer_network:
      name: adminer_network
    traefik_network:
      external:
         name: traefik_network
```

how do i fix the TLS error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the configurations are correct, only issue was to switch away from the staging servers to test it live

commented the following lines in `traefik_docker_compose.yaml` file

```
...
...
...
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
     
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

...
...
...
```

removed the content of the `./letsencrypt/` folder or delete the acme file `./letsencrypt/acme.json`

and then start traefik afresh